# C++ File reading program incrementing variable wrong in loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, fstream, file-handling, eof

I'm working on an assignment that reads data from a file, supposed student scores (I'll include below), and then my program is supposed to output how many scores are in the ranges 0-25, 25-50, and so on until 200. When I run my code, I get crazy numbers, such as, there are 120412409 scores in the ranges 0-25, but none in 25-50, and about 2000 in 75-100. I believe there is an error in my loop structure, incrementing the variable wrong when it finds a match for that range, but I am unable to figure it out.

I've tried, unsuccessfully implementing the check for the ranges in a function, but that seemed to just make it worse.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
    {
    //Variable Declare
    std::ifstream scores;
    int tastyData;
    int range0to24;
    int range25to49;
    int range50to74;
    int range75to99;
    int range100to124;
    int range125to149;
    int range150to174;
    int range175to200;

    //Opening File
    scores.open("data.txt");

    //Main Loop
    while (scores.fail())
        {
        scores >> tastyData;
        if (tastyData <= 24)
            {
            range0to24 = range0to24 + 1;
            }
            else if (tastyData <= 49 && tastyData > 24)
            {
            range25to49 = range25to49 + 1;
            }
            else if (tastyData <= 74 && tastyData > 49)
            {
            range50to74 = range50to74 + 1;
            }
            else if (tastyData <= 99 && tastyData > 74)
            {
            range75to99 = range75to99 + 1;
            }
            else if (tastyData <= 124 && tastyData > 99)
            {
            range100to124 = range100to124 + 1;
            }
            else if (tastyData <= 149 && tastyData > 124)
            {
            range125to149 = range125to149 + 1;
            }
            else if (tastyData <= 174 && tastyData > 149)
            {
            range150to174 = range150to174 + 1;
            }
            else if (tastyData <= 199 && tastyData > 174)
            {
            range175to200 = range175to200 + 1;
            }
        }
        scores.close();
        std::cout << range0to24 << "\n";
        std::cout << range25to49 << "\n";
        std::cout << range50to74 << "\n";
        std::cout << range75to99 << "\n";
        std::cout << range100to124 << "\n";
        std::cout << range125to149 << "\n";
        std::cout << range150to174 << "\n";
        std::cout << range175to200 << "\n";
    }
```

This is data.txt

76, 89, 150, 135, 200, 76, 12, 100, 150, 28, 178, 189, 167,
200, 175, 150, 87, 99, 129, 149, 176,
200, 87, 35, 157, 189

I expect the program to output how many entries in each range, such as
range0to24 = 1
range25to49 = 2 
and so on.

EDIT: My issue has now been solved. The initialization and parsing was the main issues. Thank you to everyone who helped.

Comment: Initialize your variables.

Comment: Pop quiz: the first time `range0to24 = range0to24 + 1;` executes, what is the current, the initial value of this variable? Use your debugger to figure out the answer, and figure out why is that, and you'll figure out the answer to your question.

Comment: Whenever you have an input statement such as `scores >> tastyData;` you must check that it worked,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you allocate memory for a variable without giving it a value, the value will be a garbage one. Meaning that you can't be sure of it.
In C++, you always should initialize your variable.

Morehover, I guess you meant `while (!scores.fail())` instead of `while (scores.fail())`

If you want another way to sort your scores, you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int rangeStep = 10;

    std::map<int, size_t> sortedScores;

    std::vector<int> scores { 76, 89, 150, 135, 200, 76, 12, 100, 150, 28, 178, 189, 167, 200, 175, 150, 87, 99, 129, 149, 176, 200, 87, 35, 157, 189 };

    for (int score : scores)
    {
        ++sortedScores[score / rangeStep];
    }

    for (const auto& element : sortedScores)
    {
        std::cout << "Range [" << element.first * rangeStep << "," << (element.first + 1) * rangeStep << "] => " << element.second << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs

```
Range [10,20] => 1
Range [20,30] => 1
Range [30,40] => 1
Range [70,80] => 2
Range [80,90] => 3
Range [90,100] => 1
Range [100,110] => 1
Range [120,130] => 1
Range [130,140] => 1
Range [140,150] => 1
Range [150,160] => 4
Range [160,170] => 1
Range [170,180] => 3
Range [180,190] => 2
Range [200,210] => 3
```

Your file parsing is wrong too, you can use something like :

```
std::vector<int> ReadScoresFromFile(const std::string& p_filename)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::fstream file(p_filename);
    std::string line;

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        std::stringstream   linestream(line);
        std::string         value;

        while (getline(linestream, value, ','))
        {
            result.push_back(std::atoi(value.c_str()));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and store the result into the `std::vector<int> scores` variable.

Comment: Thank you, that was a stupid error of mine. I updated the code, but I'm still getting a strange output. It now reports 0-25 to have 1 entry, and 75-99 to have 1 entry, but the rest none. I'm not sure what's going wrong now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? Should I use a different type rather than txt?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized your variables, resulting in undefined behavior. Since you're using them as counters, you should explicitly initialize them to zeroes:

```
int range0to24 = 0;
int range25to49 = 0;
int range50to74 = 0;
int range75to99 = 0;
int range100to124 = 0;
int range125to149 = 0;
int range150to174 = 0;
int range175to200 = 0;
```

Comment: Of course, I knew it would be something simple like that. Thank you, that was a stupid error of mine. I updated the code, but I'm still getting a strange output. It now reports 0-25 to have 1 entry, and 75-99 to have 1 entry, but the rest none. I'm not sure what's going wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not declaring variable globally, so you must define them.
Add `=0` after your counters or declare them globally but global declaration is part of bad coding practice so try to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. Your range variables are uninitialized. What do you expect the result of `? + 1` would be?

You can fix that by initializing your variables when you declare them:

```
int range0to24 = 0;
int range25to49 = 0;
int range50to74 = 0;
...
```

2. Your while loop is checking for `scores.fail()` to be true to continue, the loop will only be entered if opening the file failed!

Use `while (!scores.fail())` instead.

3. Your `if` `else if` structure has some redundant conditions.

```
if (tastyData <= 24)
{
    range0to24 = range0to24 + 1;
}
else if (tastyData <= 49 && tastyData > 24)
{
    range25to49 = range25to49 + 1;
}
else if ...
```

If the first `if (tastyData <= 24)` is entered, then none of the `else if` blocks will be entered. If the first condition is not true, then `tastyData` is necessarily greater than 24 and therefore the `tastyData > 24` condition on the next block is unnecessary. This logic cascades all the way down, you only need to check if `tastyData` is `<=` the next score tier if you are using `else if`.

---

I also took the chance to simplify your code and show how you can use an array and some integer math instead of several hard-coded score variables and a huge `if else if` structure.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Set up the 'bins' for counting scores
    int max = 200;
    int binSize = 25;
    int binCount = max / binSize;

    int* bins = new int[binCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < binCount; i++)
    {
        bins[i] = 0;
    }

    // Open the scores file
    std::fstream scores("data.txt");
    std::string line;
    // Read each text line in the file
    while (getline(scores, line))
    {
        std::stringstream linestream(line);
        std::string       value;

        // Read each comma-separated value in a line
        while (getline(linestream, value, ','))
        {
            int tastyData = std::atoi(value.c_str());

            int index = (tastyData / binSize);
            if (index >= binCount) continue;

            bins[index]++;
        }
    }

    scores.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < binCount; i++)
    {
        std::cout << bins[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] bins;

    return 0;
}
```

*Updated to use Adrien Givry's file parsing fixes.